# Trouble implementing gridbased pathfinding with limited turns

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, game-development

I'm in the process of making a 2d, gridbased game and have reached a standstill due to challenging code. I need to navigate from one cell in the grid to another if possible, but with a maximum of 2 turns.

[image: See here]

The red ball is the goal, and the green paths are ones that are valid, "turns" are highlighted by a blue circle.

Without brute forcing the issue and checking every posssible path how could this be done? I've experimented with a few ideas along with an a* implementation, but no luck so far. Any ideas, using unity's API or anything else is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are the constraints? Will you ever be allowed more than 2 turns? Can you only turn 90° in a turn, or can you perform a 180° turn that counts as 1 single turn?

Comment: Also, do you really need to work out every possible combination? Surely it would be easier to do the following: 1. Set a limited number of turns, 2. Let the player proceed, and each time the player chooses to turn, decrement the number of available turns left, 3. If there are 0 turns left, is the player facing the endpoint (red circle)? If yes, then this is a valid path and the player should continue to the end, if no then the player has failed.
What's your reason for wanting to know every possible valid path?

Comment: If you look at the linked image the black squares represent obstacles that cannot be crossed, you will never be allowed more than 2 turns but you can do less than 2. The distance traveled is irrelevant, only importance is whether it can reach, and the entire movement takes place in the same turn. Speaking of turns I can't imagine a situation where a 180 would make sense. The game state stays unchanged during any movement. Hope this explains everything

Comment: How does the player choose when to perform a turn?

Comment: Just saw your new comment now, the player doesn't move the actor manually. The player only clicks on the desired location, after this, whether a legal path exists needs to be decided. If the player moved on own accord, pathfinding wouldn't be needed. If a legal path exists, the actor is moved from the current position to the goal.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19437453/488657 That should give you a path with minimal turns. From there you'd have to figure out of it is less than your maximum.

Comment: I see, so you want to know if reaching the goal is possible, and ideally find the shortest path that requires two turns. I would suggest using Dijkstra's algorithm, but limiting the search by number of turns. E.g. for each node visited, mark down the direction it was visited from. If that node then visits another node using a different direction, deduct 1 from the number of turns left available to that node. Eventually you will have paths that die out as there are no available turns left. Once the target node is reached, you'll have the shortest path that reaches the target within 2 turns.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using normal A* by creating a specially-designed directed weighted graph from your original grid.

The trick is to create a graph with multiple "layers".  Layer 0 represents 0 turns having been made so far, layer 1 represents 1 turn made, and layer 2 is 2 turns.  A node connects to its neighbors on the same layer if they can be reached without turning, and its neighbors on the next layer if they require a turn.

Hopefully this is enough information for you to create the graph, but if not, the explicit steps would be:

1. Create 6 copies of the graph, `Layer_0_Horizontal`, `Layer_0_Vertical`, `Layer_1_Horizontal`, `Layer_1_Vertical`, `Layer_2_Horizontal`, `Layer_2_Vertical`.
2. For each node in a `Horizontal` layer, remove its edges to its vertical neighbors, and replace them with edges to nodes in the next layer down, with eg. `Layer_1_Vertical` being below `Layer_0_Horizontal`.  Edges in `Layer_2` won't be replaced.  Do the same thing for `Vertical` layers / horizontal edges.
3. Create a fake 'start' node, and connect it to the two `Layer_0` nodes that represent that same grid-square with 0-weight edges.  If your A* implementation only supports one goal-node, do the same with the goal.

If you want to prefer longer paths with less turns over shorter paths with more turns *(is that even possible with only two turns??)*, give the edges between layers an extremely large weight.

Comment: Jump Point Search may also help with this, as the JPS optimization of A* specifically deals with straight lines.

Comment: @Draco18s: I don't see how JPS could be applied.  JPS only works with unweighted, undirected 2D grids, and the result of the above transformation is a weighted, directed non-2D non-grid.

Comment: JPS *finds the corners* where you need to switch layers.